# SSH into server, start screen session, change directory?

Tags: gnu-screen

I want to SSH into a server, start a screen session, `cd` into `path/to/my/script/`, and run  `test.sh` there.

As a starter, I tried

```
ssh me@myserver.com screen -dm bash -c 'cd  path/to/my/script/; pwd > ~/output.txt'
```

and expected to see `path/to/my/script/` in `output.txt`, but I see my home directory there. This means the `cd` command doesn't really work, so bash won't be able to run `test.sh`.

How may I solve this?

Comment: In my test, it does work if I add extra double quotes for command executed by ssh: `ssh me@myserver.com "screen -dm bash -c 'cd  path/to/my/script/; pwd > ~/output.txt'"`

Comment: @brm Probably your comment should be turned into an answer.

Comment: @migrc Hope you like it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer: add some extra quotes around the command, like this:

```
ssh me@myserver.com "screen -dm bash -c 'cd path/to/my/script/; pwd > ~/output.txt'"
```

To see what's going on, you can specify the `-v` option to `ssh` to obtain some debug information. In this case, you'll see a line like the following *for the original command*

```
debug1: Sending command: screen -dm bash -c cd path/to/my/script/; pwd > ~/output.txt
```

while the extra quotes change this into

```
debug1: Sending command: screen -dm bash -c 'cd path/to/my/script/; pwd > ~/output.txt'
```

So it appears that ssh just takes the arguments that were passed to it, concatenates them all, and lets the remote side split the concatenated argument list again into individual arguments. Calling the argument list `argv` (like in C), you've got something like the following in the original version:

```
argv[0] = ssh
argv[1] = me@myserver.com
argv[2] = screen
argv[3] = -dm
argv[4] = bash
argv[5] = -c
argv[6] = cd path/to/my/script/; pwd > ~/output.txt
```

Now in principle, it would have been possible for `ssh` to pass `argv[2]` to `argv[6]` as separate arguments to the other side, in which case it would probably have worked as expected. But as the debug line shows (and it also seems like this based on the source code), these arguments are concatenated to the string

```
screen -dm bash -c cd path/to/my/script/; pwd > ~/output.txt
```

which is then interpreted at the remote end. From this it's also clear why it doesn't do what you'd like: now you're executing two things in sequence, first `screen -dm bash -c cd path/to/my/script/` (so a `screen` session is started in which only the directory is changed) is executed from the home directory, and then `pwd > ~/output.txt` is executed, also from the home directory.

For completeness, the arguments for the command with the double quotes are

```
argv[0] = ssh
argv[1] = me@myserver.com
argv[2] = screen -dm bash -c 'cd path/to/my/script/; pwd > ~/output.txt'
```

causing `screen -dm bash -c 'cd path/to/my/script/; pwd > ~/output.txt'` to be sent to the other side (as shown by the debug line), which does work as intended.

Comment: Really good answer!

Comment: This works, thanks! But what if I need to expand variables within the single quotes? Like `cmd=pwd; ssh me@myserver.com "screen -dm bash -c 'cd path/to/my/script/; ${cmd} > ~/output.txt'"`. Like that, `cmd` doesn't get expanded...

Comment: Yes, within single quotes shell variables don't get substituted. You can use escaped double quotes however: `ssh me@myserver.com "screen -dm bash -c \"cd path/to/my/script/; ${cmd} > ~/output.txt\""`

Answer (score 2):

The comment from @brm is the right answer. Just add the extra double quotes and it will work:

```
ssh me@myserver.com "screen -dm bash -c 'cd path/to/my/script/; pwd > ~/output.txt'"
```